# How to show that the images of inverse pair of a group is also an inverse pair?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f : A \to A'$ be a group isomorphism. If $a$ and $b$ are inverse pairs in G, then $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are also inverse pairs in G'

Attempt: Let × be the binary operation on A and • the binary operation on A'. Then f(a) • f(b) = f(a × b) = f(e), where e is the identity element of A. How can I continue this?

Comment: What you wrote shows that $f(b)=f(a)^{-1}$.

Comment: @lulu Not yet, because JD doesn't seem to know that $f(e_G)=e_{G'}$, hence he still must prove it. JD: see the link to the duplicate and note that $f$ does not need to be an isomorphism. A morphism suffices.